# How to add Height constraint to UITable view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I am creating a chatting application.
I am showing the messages in a `UILabel` and I want to adjust the height of `UILabel` to the content size and according to the size of `UILabel` i want to adjust the height of `UITableViewCell`.

I successfully updated the height of `UILabel` with the help of following code:

```
[lblSender setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

 NSString *text = [messagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIFont *font  = lblSender.font;
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(lblSender.frame.size.width,9999);
    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text
                                    attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];

 float height = rect.size.height;
    CGRect newFrame = [lblSender frame];
    newFrame.size.height = height;

    [lblSender addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:[lblSender(==%f)]",lblSender.frame.size.width]
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(lblSender)]];

    [lblSender addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[lblSender(==%f)]",newFrame.size.height]
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(lblSender)]];


    [lblSender setFrame:newFrame];

    [lblSender setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
```

From this I am getting the UITable Like this:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iqU9.png) 
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifY6f.png)

When I do same with then cell then I am not getting any result how can I do so.

Comment: I don't think you need to add any constraint for cell, you just need to return calculated cell height in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` For more see [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout)

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the height of the cell from within the cell. To set different height for the cell, you need to return the desired height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function of `UITableViewDelegate`. [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)

From the looks of your code so far, you probably should save height in a dictionary for its indexPath and call `reloadData` on your tableView. Then when this function is called, you should return the height saved for its indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Set estimated height of the cell as `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0` and don't override `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method of table, if you have applied constraints correctly inside `tableViewCell`, height will be calculated automatically  . For detailed implementation see [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Reload your cell and specify cell height in this method as per your indexPath

(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

You cannot set constraints on a UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSAttributedString` to determine the height of a cell is very costly in term of ressources - time & computing -, if you have a lot (more than 100) items in your `UITableView`, you will have a laggy scroll.

The best option for you, has it seems that you only have 1 `UILabel` inside your cell, is to create 4 `constraints` to the `UILabel` (up,down,left,right), set `self.tableView.rowHeight` as well as `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight` property to a default size. You don't have to implement the delegates methods (`heightForRowAtIndex:` and `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndex:`)

Then you want your UILabel to expand itself, so you have to set the `numberOfLines` property to 0.